# What is the difference between these two usages of functional component in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

What is the difference in these two usages of code?
FirstExample does lose focus every input change (It looks like every change causes rerender)..
SecondExample does not lose focus and works as intended.

example

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import {
  InputBase,
} from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ first: "", second: "" });

  const FirstExample = () => {
    return (
      <InputBase
        id={"first"}
        placeholder={"first"}
        multiline
        value={state.first}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setState((prevState) => {
            return {...prevState, first: e.target.value };
        })}}
      />
    );
  };

  const SecondExample = () => {
    return (
      <InputBase
        id={"second"}
        placeholder={"second"}
        multiline
        value={state.second}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setState((prevState) => {
            return {...prevState, second: e.target.value };
        })}}
      />
    );
  };

  return <div className="App">
    <FirstExample/>
    {SecondExample()}
  </div>;
}
```

Can somebody explain to me what and why there is a such difference?

there is codesandbox example: [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-water-i6gqy?file=/src/App.jsx:0-831)

Comment: Please fix your example link, because that just goes to a new default example. Having said that: open your dev tools and look at the very informative errors. It even links to the documentation about this. No need to post on SO in this case.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i've fixed sandbox link. I just have error of "React version not specified in eslint", can you tell me what documentation you mentioned?

Comment: I think you should read some articles about reference types in javascript and spread operator. Because in your case, you are working with reference types but in the wrong way.
Try this on your setState method calls:
`setState({...state, first: e.target.value });
setState({...state, second: e.target.value });`

Comment: Yep, works just fine, before i had it done in that way, and then i read about setState in class components that it merges changes by default and i changed implementation. Despite this it does not explain problem of losing focus in first input.

Answer (score 0):

First, the input losing its value: That's happens because the way you used the setState. Your new state consist of just an object containing the [second] key, you did not preserve the rest of the object. The correct way to do it should be:

```js
      <InputBase
        id={"second"}
        placeholder={"second"}
        multiline
        value={state.second}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setState({...state, second: e.target.value });
        }}
      />
```

So you make sure to get the whole object first, and override what you want.

The first input is loosing it's focus because the component is being re-created everytime the state of the App updates. If you insert the input inside the return(), or outside of the App, to then call it, it will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you about setState, i thought it is similar to setState in class component and it would merge by default. About second part i still do not understand why just first one looses focus, it is same component (for second one state also changes) just used differently.

Comment: I actually was not sure of why, so I went looking and found [this really nice article](https://dev.to/igor_bykov/react-calling-functional-components-as-functions-1d3l)  explaining this exact thing. I learned a lot.